# Does RabbitMQ's MQTT plugin write messages to disk by default?

Tags: rabbitmq

I'm testing the RabbitMQ's MQTT plugin on a server running in Docker (`rabbitmq:3.11.15-management` image), by publishing messages with a certain rate, basically by running this command:

```bash
while true; do mosquitto_pub <parameters>; sleep 0.1; done
```

I have no subscribers while doing this. However, I'm seeing on the host where RabbitMQ server is running (the server runs in a Docker container), a certain increase in disk writing (monitored via Netdata), in the exact moment when I'm publishing the messages. After ceasing the publishing, the writing throughput decreases.

Initially I thought it may have something to do with the server logs being written on disk by Docker, because each time the mosquitto_pub runs, a connection is performed and this gets logged by RabbitMQ. But I've disabled these logs with `log.connection.level = warning`.

Does RabbitMQ persist these published messages on disk by default?

---

rabbitmq.conf

```
mqtt.allow_anonymous = false
mqtt.vhost = mqtt
mqtt.listeners.tcp.default = 1883
mqtt.listeners.ssl.default = 8883

listeners.ssl.default = 5671
ssl_options.cacertfile = /mnt/certs/fullchain.pem
ssl_options.certfile = /mnt/certs/fullchain.pem
ssl_options.keyfile = /mnt/certs/privkey.pem
ssl_options.verify = verify_peer
ssl_options.fail_if_no_peer_cert = false

log.connection.level = warning
```

---

enabled_plugins.erl

```
[rabbitmq_management,rabbitmq_mqtt,rabbitmq_shovel].
```